# F#: Getting exception for --help argument when using Argu

Tags: f#, f#-argu

I'm very new to F# and I'm trying to create a console application that takes parameters. I found the [Argu](http://fsprojects.github.io/Argu/index.html) library and have been trying to get a basic example to work. The following works as expection if passed the `--commanda` or `--commandb` arguments, but I get an exception if I try `--help`.

```
open System
open Argu

type CliArguments =
    | CommandA
    | CommandB
with 
    interface IArgParserTemplate with
        member s.Usage = 
            match s with 
            | CommandA -> "CommandA - Do something" 
            | CommandB -> "CommandB - Do something"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let parser = ArgumentParser.Create<CliArguments>()
    let results = parser.Parse argv

    results.GetAllResults()
    |> List.iter (fun x ->
                    match x with
                    | CommandA -> printfn "CommandA"
                    | CommandB -> printfn "CommandB")

    0
```

The exception is:

```
> .\Argu_sample.exe --help

Unhandled Exception: Argu.ArguParseException: USAGE: Argu_sample.exe [--help] [--commanda] [--commandb]

OPTIONS:

    --commanda            CommandA - Do something
    --commandb            CommandB - Do something
    --help                display this list of options.

   at Argu.ExceptionExiter.Argu-IExiter-Exit[a](String msg, ErrorCode errorCode)
   at Argu.ArgumentParser`1.Parse(FSharpOption`1 inputs, FSharpOption`1 configurationReader, FSharpOption`1 ignoreMissing, FSharpOption`1 ignoreUnrecognized, FSharpOption`1 raiseOnUsage)
   at Program.main(String[] argv) in C:\Data\FSharp\Argu-sample\Argu-sample\Program.fs:line 18
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**UPDATED CODE WITH SOLUTION:**

Based on AMieres comment, I ended up using `try with`:

```
open System
open Argu

type CliArguments =
    | CommandA
    | CommandB
with 
    interface IArgParserTemplate with
        member s.Usage = 
            match s with 
            | CommandA -> "CommandA - Do something" 
            | CommandB -> "CommandB - Do something"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let parser = ArgumentParser.Create<CliArguments>()

    try 
        let results = parser.Parse argv

        results.GetAllResults()
        |> List.iter (fun x ->
                        match x with
                        | CommandA -> printfn "CommandA"
                        | CommandB -> printfn "CommandB") 
        0
    with
    | :? ArguParseException as ex ->
        printfn "%s" ex.Message
        1
    | ex ->
        printfn "Internal Error:"
        printfn "%s" ex.Message
        2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seems to be an undocumented feature.
The `--help` is treated as an exception and you need to either handle it with `try with` or provide a handler.

Check out the sample in Github: https://github.com/fsprojects/Argu/blob/master/samples/Argu.Samples.LS/Program.fs.

In it, the parser is created with an error handler:

```
let errorHandler = ProcessExiter(colorizer = function ErrorCode.HelpText -> None | _ -> Some ConsoleColor.Red)
let parser = ArgumentParser.Create<LsArguments>(programName = "ls", errorHandler = errorHandler)
```

When in doubt consult the code:
https://github.com/fsprojects/Argu/blob/b1569917af314dfd3b77fb79fec2a157a51324c7/src/Argu/Types.fs#L29

```
/// Error codes reported by Argu
type ErrorCode =
    | HelpText = 0
    | AppSettings = 1
    | CommandLine = 2
    | PostProcess = 3
```

Comment: Thanks @AMieres, based on your answer I ended up using `try with`. I got the actual `try with` code from [this page](https://enricosada.github.io/openfsharp-workshop/consoleapp/)

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide an error handler:

```
let errorHandler = ProcessExiter(colorizer = function ErrorCode.HelpText -> None | _ -> Some ConsoleColor.Red)
let parser = ArgumentParser.Create<CliArguments>(errorHandler = errorHandler)
```